# Sabre Hotel Rate Description Request

Tags: soap, rate, sabre

I am trying to get Hotel Rate Description using Sabre SOAP API. But I am getting error which I am unable to debug.

My request payload is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">from</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">ws</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>{{CPAID}}</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>pricedrop</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML"></eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ</eb:Action>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">
<!--                  Use Security token from Authentication Request  -->
            Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/CERTG!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3460256494356271327!1683974!0
            </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <HotelRateDescriptionRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.3.0">
        <AvailRequestSegment>
        <GuestCounts Count="1"/>
        <HotelSearchCriteria>
        <Criterion>
        <HotelRef HotelCode="0017804"/>
        </Criterion>
        </HotelSearchCriteria>
        <RatePlanCandidates>
        <RatePlanCandidate CurrencyCode="USD" DCA_ProductCode="A1B2C3D"/>
        </RatePlanCandidates>
        <TimeSpan End="12-28" Start="12-25"/>
        </AvailRequestSegment>
        </HotelRateDescriptionRQ>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But I got 1VERIFY FORMAT error. The response is given below.

```
<soap-env:Body>
        <HotelRateDescriptionRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.3.0">
            <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
                <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2015-12-11T03:01:21-06:00">
                    <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                        <stl:Message>1VERIFY FORMAT                                                 </stl:Message>
                        <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
                    </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                </stl:Error>
            </stl:ApplicationResults>
        </HotelRateDescriptionRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
```

All my Value in request payload seems correct except for DCA_ProductCode which I didn't understand. Sabre documentation also doesn't explain much about DCA_ProductCode.

What might possibly go wrong in my request payload?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the value {{CPAID}} of the CPAId element in the soap header being valid (unless that's a reference to a variable or you masked it somehow) - normally you would submit your IPCC there.

Anyway, from the description of the Hotel Rate Description service:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/hotel/search/hotel_rate_description

"Please note that independent HRD, i-HRD, functionality contained within HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ is not available to users by default. i-HRD negates the need for basing the rate query from a HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ response. In order to utilize this functionality authorization is required. Please contact your sales representative for further details."

It seems that the functionality needs to be activated first.
You can contact the Sabre Web Services support team at webservices.support@sabre.com - and ask for iHRD activation.

You'll need to provide your IPCC, and Sabre Web Services environment you're using (CERT / PROD).

Comment: fcarreno: We replace {{CPAID}} with the one we got from Sabre. The security token in the question is also valid at the time I posted the question.

Comment: thanks Gagan - if you get the iHRD feature enabled, you should be able to get a valid response from the service, then.

Comment: How do I know if iHRD feature is enabled for the account? The account that I currently use is created by my client.

Comment: You can have your client do the Sabre command HIP* (on Sabre a travel agent screen). The response will look something similar to this 
(look for INDEPENDENT HRD and its status on the next line):

...INDEPENDENT HRD   
ON...

Or use the SabreCommand (SOAP service) and do the same:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/utility/Send_Sabre_Command