# verify format error in HotelRateDescriptionRQ

Tags: sabre

i'm getting verify format error while searching hotel rate description using sabre soap api. my request is following:

```
<HotelRateDescriptionRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.3.0">
        <AvailRequestSegment>
            <GuestCounts Count="2"/>
            <HotelSearchCriteria>
                <Criterion>
                    <HotelRef HotelCode="0039013"/>
                </Criterion>
            </HotelSearchCriteria>
            <TimeSpan End="04-04" Start="04-01"/>
        </AvailRequestSegment>
    </HotelRateDescriptionRQ>
```

and the response is following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap-env:Header><eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1"><eb:From><eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">sws3-crt.cert.sabre.com</eb:PartyId></eb:From><eb:To><eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">7973</eb:PartyId></eb:To><eb:CPAId>OH88</eb:CPAId><eb:ConversationId>y4JiO-0PTQn5fm5SRTPz-1459075755</eb:ConversationId><eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML"/><eb:Action>HotelRateDescriptionLLSRS</eb:Action><eb:MessageData><eb:MessageId>41ade332-41f5-4d1e-ad9a-c9b8d91a8817@176</eb:MessageId><eb:Timestamp>2016-03-27T10:50:32</eb:Timestamp></eb:MessageData></eb:MessageHeader><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/CERTG!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3422351642743054173!493550!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken></wsse:Security></soap-env:Header><soap-env:Body><HotelRateDescriptionRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.3.0">
 <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
  <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2016-03-27T05:50:32-05:00">
   <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
    <stl:Message>1VERIFY FORMAT                                                 </stl:Message>
    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
   </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
  </stl:Error>
 </stl:ApplicationResults>
</HotelRateDescriptionRS></soap-env:Body></soap-env:Envelope>
```

so what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219749/sabre-hotel-rate-description-request

Answer (score 0):

look I can use **HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ** using RPH atribute.
RPH atribute can be found by **HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ**.

```
<soap-env:Body>
      <ns:HotelRateDescriptionRQ ReturnHostCommand="false" Version="2.3.0">
         <ns:AvailRequestSegment>
            <ns:RatePlanCandidates>
               <ns:RatePlanCandidate RPH="001" />
            </ns:RatePlanCandidates>
         </ns:AvailRequestSegment>
      </ns:HotelRateDescriptionRQ>
   </soap-env:Body>
```